# Github project won't update due to large folder size

Tags: git, github

I recently compressed one of my projects in order to update my website that's on cpanel. Unfortunately I forgot to delete the folder. Today when I tried to update my project on github, I got an error saying ' File public.zip is 158.52 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB'. I then proceeded to delete the folder manually. But then when I did the git push command, it brought up the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2PXx.jpg) again. Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

Comment: You can’t just delete the file if it has already been committed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history